# How to save multiple level nested object in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I read the example on http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/ which gives the following snippet as an example, but I'm not fully following it.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'profile')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
        return user
```

The questions are,

1. Why it's creating a user object first then creating a profile object with it `Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)` instead of create a user object with a profile object?
2. How to handle multiple level of nested objects, say if profile class has another Many-to-Many relationship field under it? If I have another overwriting create() defined inside `ProfileSerializer()`, with the example above will be it triggered?

EDIT:

I now get that User is Profile's foreign key field so that you have to have a user object before creating a profile one. My case here might be a little different, or is it the same scenario but I'm still not fully getting the point?

```
class Endpoint(models.Model):
    ....

class ConnectedHost(models.Model):
    ....
    endpoints = models.ManyToManyField(Endpoint)

class Connection(models.Model):
    ....        
    connectedhosts = models.ManyToManyField(ConnectedHost)
```

And basically my Connection object data will look like,

```
{
  "ConnectedHost": {
    "endpoints": [
      {
        "URL": "111.111.111.111"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How should I implement Serializer create() functions here for each one? And am I using ManyToMany relationship wrong here?

Comment: In Django, before you save the object, all its foreignkeys must exist in database. This is why you should create User first. For second, I haven't tried yet but it's sense to have multiple serializers if you have many nested relations.

Comment: Thanks @brsbilgic, I got the idea now. What I'm facing is nested Many-to-Many relationships, so I'm still a little confused on that. Let me give more details to my question.